# Wrapper for 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

My aim is to have a struct which contains a pointer to a 2D array of unsigned chars as well as its width and height so that I can correctly retrieve data back from it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct wrapper {
    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;
    unsigned char ***data;
};

inline unsigned char retrieveValue(struct wrapper *wrapper, unsigned short x, unsigned short y) {
    typedef unsigned char (*myCast)[wrapper->height][wrapper->width];
    return (unsigned char)((*(myCast)(wrapper->data))[y][x]);
}

unsigned char testWrapperData[2][2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };

struct wrapper wrapper = {
    2,
    2,
    (unsigned char ***)testWrapperData,
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", retrieveValue(&wrapper, 1, 0));
    return 1;
}
```

This is what I am currently using, it works but I'm pretty sure I'm doing some things wrong (not sure if it should be just unsigned char ** instead of unsigned char ***).

Also I'd like to remove the typedef of myCast so that I can have it all on one line.

Comment: You can have what you want, but the initialization is going to be different.

Comment: What is wrong with my initialization?

Comment: You have incompatible types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triple pointer is not necessary, you can either use an `unsigned char*` or a `void*`. But that's next to irrelevant since you don't plan to use the declared type of the pointer anyway. In either case, there are no several levels of pointers involved, the address you store in `wrapper->data` is the address of the first `unsigned char` in the 2D array. The access of 2D arrays is pure pointer arithmetic via the infamous array-pointer decay.

You can try to clean up your code in several ways ("try to" because the effect of some of this is disputable).

1. Remove the cast to `unsigned char` from `retrieveValue()`, so that your compiler can check whether `(myCast)` used the correct type.
2. Use the type that `testWrapperData` decays into. This removes the outer array layer from the cast and the usage of the casted type. This is perfectly equivalent to the code you posted, because the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element, it just has a different type that leads to one more level of pointer decay.

   ```
   inline unsigned char retrieveValue(struct wrapper *wrapper, unsigned short x, unsigned short y) {
       typedef unsigned char (*myCast)[wrapper->width];
       return ((myCast)wrapper->data)[y][x];
   }

   struct wrapper wrapper = {
       2,
       2,
       (void*)testWrapperData,
   };
   ```
3. You can also inline the cast, but this really is a matter of taste:

   ```
   inline unsigned char retrieveValue(struct wrapper *wrapper, unsigned short x, unsigned short y) {
       return ((unsigned char (*)[wrapper->width])wrapper->data)[y][x];
   }
   ```
4. You can encapsulate the cast into a macro:

   ```
   #define getWrapperData(wrapper) ((unsigned char (*)[(wrapper)->width])(wrapper)->data)

   inline unsigned char retrieveValue(struct wrapper *wrapper, unsigned short x, unsigned short y) {
       return getWrapperData(wrapper)[y][x];
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct wrapper {
    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;
    void *data;
};

inline unsigned char retrieveValue(struct wrapper *wrapper, unsigned short x, unsigned short y) {
    typedef unsigned char (*myCast)[wrapper->height][wrapper->width];
    return (*(myCast)wrapper->data)[y][x];
}

unsigned char testWrapperData[2][2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };

struct wrapper wrapper = {
    2,
    2,
    &testWrapperData,
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", retrieveValue(&wrapper, 1, 0));
    return 1;
}
```